# Time conversation problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this question on a online IQ website, My answer is noon, But my friends are says as 4Pm. what is the correct answer

> 16 hrs later would be noon in Moscow, which is 4 hours ahead of where
>   we are right now. What is the current time where we are right now?
>
> a. Midnight
>
> b. 8 pm
>
> c. 4 pm
>
> d. Noon

Answer (score 1):

Your friends are right, I think.  In sixteen hours, it'll be noon in Moscow, which means it is currently 8 p.m. in Moscow, which means it is currently 4 p.m. where you are.